# Searching techniques via Nautilus or otherwise

Tags: search

Lets say I have following files in a folder

- Blue-Green-Red
- Red-Yellow-Blue
- Green-Black-red

Now I want to search files having 'green' **and** 'red' as part of their names (case insensitive), how i do that via nautilus or any GUI? Back in windows it was easy via total commander...especially if you are dealing with media files & want to 'queue play' only files meeting above criteria thus terminal options are of no use!

Comment: You asked about "Total Commander", I don't know what that software is like *now*, but have a look at mc ("Midnight Commander").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Nautilus, type:

```
green red
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the find command as follows:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*red.*green.*|.*green.*red.*'
```

What this does:

find = Just what it says

. = where

-maxdepth 1 = current folder only

-regextype posix-egrep = specifies that we're using Regular expressions of type posix-egrep

-iregex = case insensitve expression

.* = any character repeated 0 or more times

expression1|expression2 = either expression1 or expression2 (in this case anything + red + anything + green + anything OR anything + green + anything + red + anything

Comment: Thanks for explanation but terminal options aren't the answer when after searching specified files we have to en-queue them in VLC player

Comment: That was not specified in the question, but now that you say it, you can enqueue such a list to VLC by piping the results to an .m3u file like this: `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*red.*green.*|.*green.*red.*' > playlist.m3u`. Then open the file in VLC.

Answer (score 0):

I think searching for **red green** lists the files and folders with both search terms in the name. However, you can always search for **green*red**, and then for **red*green**, it will give the desired results. I do not know if there is even an AND boolean operand that you can use in nautilus.